# Handlebars.js Partial Parameters w/ Conditional Statement

Tags: javascript, json, conditional-statements, handlebars.js

I am including a partial in my template which I want to send a single parameter to (for the `class`), but I have some conditions I'd like to put in front of it, so I'm trying this:

```
{{> 'navItem' toggleClass="utility-toggle{{#if isAccount}} utility-toggle--account{{else if isCart}} utility-toggle--cart{{/if}}"}}
```

However, when I'm outputting that `toggleClass` value (`class={{toggleClass}}`), it is outputting the if statement as a string:

```
class="utility-toggle{{#if isAccount}} utility-toggle--account{{else if isCart}} utility-toggle--cart{{/if}}"
```

Is there a way to get the if statement to execute prior to sending it through to the partial? I looked into helpers for concatenation but I couldn't find anything that ALSO had the conditional piece.

Comment: I don't think there are very good options for what you are trying to achieve. I am thinking that the best approach would be to move all of the classes into the partial and use specific parameters to determine which get rendered. Otherwise, I think you would need a custom helper to compose your `toggleClass` string or something messy/complicated like [Partial Blocks](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-blocks).

Comment: Here is an example that preserves the `toggleClass` partial parameter by using a custom inline-helper to generate the class string: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/6eL8a5tj/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I couldn't find an exact answer to this question, but the way that I worked around it:

I had some handlebars helpers:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper( 'add', function( a, b ) {
    return a + b;
} );

// Logical helpers
// Examples at source: https://gist.github.com/servel333/21e1eedbd70db5a7cfff327526c72bc5
const reduceOp = function( args, reducer ){
    args = Array.from( args );
    args.pop(); // => options
    var first = args.shift();
    return args.reduce( reducer, first );
};
Handlebars.registerHelper( {
    eq  : function(){ return reduceOp( arguments, ( a,b ) => a === b ); },
    ne  : function(){ return reduceOp( arguments, ( a,b ) => a !== b ); },
    lt  : function(){ return reduceOp( arguments, ( a,b ) => a  <  b ); },
    gt  : function(){ return reduceOp( arguments, ( a,b ) => a  >  b ); },
    lte : function(){ return reduceOp( arguments, ( a,b ) => a  <= b ); },
    gte : function(){ return reduceOp( arguments, ( a,b ) => a  >= b ); },
    and : function(){ return reduceOp( arguments, ( a,b ) => a  && b ); },
    or  : function(){ return reduceOp( arguments, ( a,b ) => a  || b ); },
} );
```

So leveraging a few of those helpers, I achieved what I was going for with:

```
{{> 'navItem' toggleClass=(add 'utility-toggle' (or (or (and isAccount ' utility-toggle--account' ) (and isCart ' utility-toggle--cart')) ''))
```

Explaining it:

1. `and` will first evaluate the first parameter and then if it's true, it will evaluate & output the second (string) parameter. So, if `isAccount` is true and `isCart` is false, it would be `(add 'utility-toggle' (or (or ' utility-toggle--account' false) ''))`
2. Then, the `or` will evaluate & output the first string that is true, so `(add 'utility-toggle' (or ' utility-toggle--account' '')`
3. Then the outer `or`... `(add 'utility-toggle' ' utility-toggle--account')`
4. Resulting in `utility-toggle utility-toggle--account`

Definitely not super straightforward to read though... if anyone has a better / clearer solution, happy to consider it!